# PDO: Can't connect to mysql when host is set in variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm in trouble. I'm trying to connect remote mysql server with pdo (php 5.4.12). With this code it's connect normally:

```
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=newdb', $user, $pass);
```

But, if i try set host with variable, like this:

```
$host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';    
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname=newdb', $user, $pass);
```

It's just thinks sometime, and tell me:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message ' in
>   D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 21
>   21 it's line of creating new PDO object.

Ok, i'm try to catch exception (sorry, it's new for me), and now i have this:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Can you help me, please?

Double quoting not helps

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=newdb", $user, $pass);
```

Nothing changed.

var_dump('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname=newdb');

> string 'mysql:host=xx.xx.xxx.xxx;dbname=newdb' (length=37)

Way with {} not helped for me.

Ok, the situation becomes clear. I'm try to connect another server on another IP, and it's normally connected. Can it be mysql server security options?

Comment: "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message" is usually followed by an exception message. Did you forget it ? Also, what does `var_dump('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname=newdb')` display ? Something correct ?

Comment: random passing thought `$dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=newdb", $user, $pass);`

Comment: Double quotes so the variable can be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";    
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname=newdb", $user, $pass);
```

The double quotes and the braces to include the var in the string as you can see here
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Elias, see my comment to the other Answer.

Comment: Sorry b__ i dont agree with you DV, but i undestand the point.
Let me update the answer then.